# Loading a mesh (obj+mtl) into WebGL using JSON

Tags: json, webgl, render

I'm starting to learn WebGL and I've no experience at all with Graphics.

I need to load a complete mesh into WebGL (Dabrovic Sponza from: http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/data/meshes.xml ). Since today the only type of model I've loaded it up was simple JSON through:

```
function loadModel(){
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "sponza.json");
    request.onreadystatechange=function (){
        if(request.readyState==4)
            handleLoadedModel(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
    }
    request.send();   
}
```

Now I've those files:

[image]

What I've done so far is:

I converted the obj to JSON with this script found online

```
    function loadObj(url)
    {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function () { processLoadObj(req) };
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

    function processLoadObj(req)
    {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            doLoadObj(req.responseText);
        }
    }

    function doLoadObj(text)
    {
        vertexArray = [ ];
        normalArray = [ ];
        textureArray = [ ];
        indexArray = [ ];

        var vertex = [ ];
        var normal = [ ];
        var texture = [ ];
        var facemap = { };
        var index = 0;

        var lines = text.split("\n");
        for (var lineIndex in lines) {
            var line = lines[lineIndex].replace(/[ \t]+/g, " ").replace(/\s\s*$/, "");

            // ignore comments
            if (line[0] == "#")
                continue;

            var array = line.split(" ");
            if (array[0] == "v") {
                // vertex
                vertex.push(parseFloat(array[1]));
                vertex.push(parseFloat(array[2]));
                vertex.push(parseFloat(array[3]));
            }
            else if (array[0] == "vt") {
                // normal
                texture.push(parseFloat(array[1]));
                texture.push(parseFloat(array[2]));
            }
            else if (array[0] == "vn") {
                // normal
                normal.push(parseFloat(array[1]));
                normal.push(parseFloat(array[2]));
                normal.push(parseFloat(array[3]));
            }
            else if (array[0] == "f") {
                // face
                if (array.length != 4) {
                    //obj.ctx.console.log("*** Error: face '"+line+"' not handled");
                    continue;
                }

                for (var i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
                    if (!(array[i] in facemap)) {
                        // add a new entry to the map and arrays
                        var f = array[i].split("/");
                        var vtx, nor, tex;

                        if (f.length == 1) {
                            vtx = parseInt(f[0]) - 1;
                            nor = vtx;
                            tex = vtx;
                        }
                        else if (f.length = 3) {
                            vtx = parseInt(f[0]) - 1;
                            tex = parseInt(f[1]) - 1;
                            nor = parseInt(f[2]) - 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            //obj.ctx.console.log("*** Error: did not understand face '"+array[i]+"'");
                            return null;
                        }

                        // do the vertices
                        var x = 0;
                        var y = 0;
                        var z = 0;
                        if (vtx * 3 + 2 < vertex.length) {
                            x = vertex[vtx*3];
                            y = vertex[vtx*3+1];
                            z = vertex[vtx*3+2];
                        }
                        vertexArray.push(x);
                        vertexArray.push(y);
                        vertexArray.push(z);

                        // do the textures
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        if (tex * 2 + 1 < texture.length) {
                            x = texture[tex*2];
                            y = texture[tex*2+1];
                        }
                        textureArray.push(x);
                        textureArray.push(y);

                        // do the normals
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        z = 1;
                        if (nor * 3 + 2 < normal.length) {
                            x = normal[nor*3];
                            y = normal[nor*3+1];
                            z = normal[nor*3+2];
                        }
                        normalArray.push(x);
                        normalArray.push(y);
                        normalArray.push(z);

                        facemap[array[i]] = index++;
                    }

                    indexArray.push(facemap[array[i]]);
                }
            }
        }

        result = {};
        result["vertexPositions"] = vertexArray;
        result["vertexNormals"] = normalArray;
        result["vertexTextureCoords"] = textureArray;
        result["indices"] = indexArray;;


        document.write(JSON.stringify(result));

    }
    </script>
    </head>


    <body onload="loadObj('model.obj');">
    </body>
```

Then put all the info into buffers (1 for text coords, 1 for vertices, 1 for normals, 1 for indices)

And finally used a single texture for everything.

The result is far beyond the dabrovic sponza (a random pic on google image show what I want), how can I use those jpg file and .mtl ?

I don't even know exactly what an mtl file is and I've no experience AT ALL with those stuff, this is my first attempt, so please be patient with me!

Also, sorry if my English is bad!

EDIT: 
Also, loading the mesh with a random model loader I found out that not all the vertices are correctly converted (e.g. I don't have the floor). Moreover if I use a texture for everything some parts (collonades) are rendered as fully transparent... maybe my converter is bad. There is a chance for me to write a decent converter ? Where I can find documentation to do so ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

apparently your OBJ converter ignores the material definitions that are included in the MTL file. Are you married to this format? Maybe load in blender and re-export as collada?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use obj. Also, loading the mesh with a random model loader I found out that not all the vertices are correctly converted (e.g. I don't have the floor). Moreover if I use a texture for everything some parts (collonades) are rendered as fully transparent... maybe my converter is bad. There is a chance for me to write a decent converter ? Where I can find documentation to do so ? Thanks again

Comment: perhaps you should render it with two-sided polygons? The floor & collonades may appear

Comment: I'm afraid I'm too a newbie to know how to this, I'm playing around with graphics since like one month ago. Can you provide me some documentation on it ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Set it in the material. If your material is, say "myMat" then set "myMat.side = THREE.DoubleSide;"  (or just assign "side: THREE.DoubleSide" as part of the material declaration)

Comment: Oh my fault, I didn't mention that I'm not using Three.js, but plain WebGL

Comment: in that case:     _gl.disable(_gl.CULL_FACE);